# 'Don't Blame It On I' vs. "Don't blame it on me"

Tags: lyrics, word-play

There is a song called ["Don't Blame It On I" by The Congos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UrKhHbDrnU).

Is there any wordplay associated with this phrase? Usually, we say "Don't you blame it on me".

Comment: Music culture don't really go by the accepted grammar rules and regulations. It is therefore, a very unorthodox statement.

Comment: It's a Jamaican band, and Jamaicans speak their own dialect (or patois) of English.

Comment: @WeatherVane - "Jamaicans speak their own dialect (or patois)" - called ['Patois'  or 'Patwah'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamaican_Patois) e.g. 'I and I' for 'we'. _Sell I a pound, of dat thing there_ (song 'Dat' by Pluto Shervington)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey a [patois](https://www.lexico.com/definition/patois) isn't exclusive to Jamaica.

Comment: 'A patois' is used of many creole type languages or dialects, but the one spoken in Jamaica is actually called _Patois_ by its speakers. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the lyrics of the song:
[Google "Don't you blame it on I"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22don%27t%20blame%20it%20on%20I%20%22%20lyrics)

It's not quite English, but an example of this:

[Wikipedia "lyaric"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iyaric)

> Iyaric, Livalect, Dread-talk or I-talk is a consciously created dialect of English in use among members of the Rastafari movement. African languages were lost among Africans when they were taken into captivity as part of the slave trade, and adherents of Rastafari teachings believe that English is an imposed colonial language.

> "I" replaces "me", which is much more commonly used in Jamaican English than in the more conventional forms. "Me" is felt to turn the person into an object, whereas "I" emphasises the subjectivity of an individual.